# bitcoin-cli: Get transaction count of wallet without listtransactions

Tags: json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I am trying to find a way to get the number of transactions returned from the JSONRPC interface without relying on listtransactions. The reason for this is that if the wallet has too many transactions (like hundreds of thousands), it can easily flood the node's memory and cause a crash. So I would like to know if there is a less intensive way to get just the number of transactions, so I can use listtransactions with the skip= and count= parameters to iterate in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I found an output field in `getwalletinfo` called `"txcount"` in the top level of the output JSON that will list the number of transactions inside the wallet.

```
{
  ...
  "txcount": 680899,
  ...
}
```